# Auto printer in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a small project. I have problems printing.
I want when I press the Print button the printer prints out. Don't Printreview.
And code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Auto printer")
window.geometry('500x400')

def close_window (): 
   window.destroy() 

def auto_print():
   os.startfile("F:/test2.png", "print")

path='F:/test.png'
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(window, image=img)
panel.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="yes")

frm_buttons = tk.Frame()
frm_buttons.pack(fill=tk.X, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

btn_close = tk.Button(master=frm_buttons, text="CLOSE", command = close_window)
btn_close.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, ipadx=10)

tn_print = tk.Button(master=frm_buttons, text="PRINT", command = auto_print)
btn_print.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, ipadx=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I  think what you are saying is that execution of  ```os.startfile("F:/test2.png", "print")``` results in the file being opened in preview mode and what you really want is for the file to be printed.  Do you want the file printed to the console or directly to the attached system printer?

Comment: Thanh  itprorh66, I want print file directly to the attached system printer

Answer (score 1):

and I found this post http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html.
I've corrected it, it's okay. But I don't understand the syntax `win32api.ShellExecute (  0,  "printto",  filename,  '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),  ".",  0)`

code:

```
def auto_print():
   filename = "F:/test.png"
   win32api.ShellExecute (  0,  "printto",  filename,  '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),  ".",  0)
```